# using reduce to calculate gini index for a node

Tags: python, functools

I am trying to apply the formula:

[image: Formula]

I am unclear why this does not work:

```py
def gini_node(node):
    count = sum(node)
    gini = functools.reduce(lambda p,c: p + (1 - (c/count)**2), node)
    print(count, gini)
    print(1 - (node[0]/count)**2, 1 - (node[1]/count)**2)
    return gini
```

Evaluating `gini([[175, 330], [220, 120]])` prints:

```
505 175.57298304087834
0.8799137339476522 0.5729830408783452
340 220.87543252595157
0.5813148788927336 0.8754325259515571
```

note that the second print statement prints the figures that I want to sum, given the example input. the return value (the first print statement's second value) should be a number between 0 and 1.

What is wrong with my reduce?

Full function I am trying to write is:

```py
import functools

def gini_node(node):
    count = sum(node)
    gini = functools.reduce(lambda p,c: p + (1 - (c/count)**2), node)
    print(count, gini)
    print(1 - (node[0]/count)**2, 1 - (node[1]/count)**2)
    return gini

def gini (groups):
    counts = [ sum(node) for node in groups ]
    count = sum(counts)
    proportions = [ n/count for n in counts ]

    return sum([ gini_node(node) * proportion for node, proportion in zip(groups, proportions)])

# test
print(gini([[175, 330], [220, 120]]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way reduce works is it takes 2 arguments from it's container(only 2)
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce
 and performs the operation given to it, then keeps on iterating the same operation over the list using 2 arguments.

```
gini = functools.reduce(lambda p,c: p + (1 - (c/count)**2), node)
```

For first node `(175, 330)` this lambda would take `175` in `p` and `330` in `c` and return you `175.57298304087834` instead we want

```
gini = functools.reduce(lambda p,c: (1 - (p/count)**2) + (1 - (c/count)**2), node)
```

I have added some print statements, let's see their output.

```
import functools

def gini_node(node):
    count = sum(node)
    gini = functools.reduce(lambda p,c: (1 - (p/count)**2) + (1 - (c/count)**2), node)
    print(count, gini)
    print(1 - (node[0]/count)**2, 1 - (node[1]/count)**2)
    return gini

def gini (groups):
    counts = [ sum(node) for node in groups ]
    count = sum(counts)
    proportions = [ n/count for n in counts ]
    print(count, counts, proportions) #This
    gini_indexes = [ gini_node(node) * proportion for node, proportion in zip(groups, proportions)]
    print(gini_indexes) #And this
    return sum(gini_indexes)

# test
print(gini([[175, 330], [220, 120]]))

rahul@RNA-HP:~$ python3 so.py
845 [505, 340] [0.5976331360946746, 0.40236686390532544]
505 1.4528967748259973 #Second number here is addition of 2 numbers below
0.8799137339476522 0.5729830408783452
340 1.4567474048442905 #Same for this
0.5813148788927336 0.8754325259515571
#The first number of this list is first 1.45289677.... * 0.597633...
#Basically the addition and then multiplication by it's proportion.
[0.868299255961099, 0.5861468847894187]
#What you are returning to final print statement is the addition of gini co-effs of each node i.e the sum of the list above
1.4544461407505178
```

An easier way to go around if there are more than 2 arguments(*)

```
 gini = sum([(1 - (p/count)**2) for p in node])
```

Works the same are the `reduce()` function defined above.

Comment: Rahul this was very good of you, but I'm afraid you are wrong. a gini coefficient is always between 0 and 1. There are groups like "country a, or array b", etc and classes within each group ("people with short hair", "characteristic b", etc). each group's gini index must sum to one, and must be multiplied by the proportion before summed so that the overall value also is between 0 and 1. Zero represents absolute equality.

Comment: What I am calculating is elegantly described here: http://shlegeris.com/gini and fully described here (but I dont understand tables in R): http://www.learnbymarketing.com/481/decision-tree-flavors-gini-info-gain/ 
a different, and far more intuitive way to calculate it, is here: https://planspace.org/2013/06/21/how-to-calculate-gini-coefficient-from-raw-data-in-python/ But for now I should implement this formula.

Comment: However, t didn't take long *at all* to get what I needed from your last code block! thank you!!! `gini = 1 - sum([ (p/count)**2 for p in node ])`

Comment: So how come here the summation goes above 1, is it because of negative co-relation ?